# vbscript launching an exe file from specialfolders

Tags: vbscript

I want to launch an exe that is a messagebox from a specialfolders using vbscript, but I get nothing. this is my code

```
option explicit
dim shellobj,startup,objShell,objFolder,filesystemobj,installdir,installname
set shellobj = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
set filesystemobj = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
installdir = "%appdata%\Microsoft"
installname = wscript.scriptname
filesystemobj.copyfile wscript.scriptfullname,installdir & installname,true
startup = shellobj.specialfolders("%appdata%\Microsoft") &"\msg.exe"
if filesystemobj.fileexists(startup) Then
  shellobj.run "wscript.exe //B " & chr(34) & startup & chr(34)    
  Wscript.Quit
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `startup = shellobj.specialfolders("%appdata%\Microsoft") &"\msg.exe"`

   The [`SpecialFolders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property doesn't expand environment variables. You need the [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8116cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method for that:

   ```
   shellobj.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%\Microsoft") & "\msg.exe"
   ```

   The `SpecialFolders` property must be used like this:

   ```
   shellobj.SpecialFolders("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\msg.exe"
   ```
2. `if filesystemobj.fileexists(startup) Then`

   Since `specialfolders("%appdata%\Microsoft")` returns an empty string the value of `startup` becomes `\msg.exe`, which doesn't exist. Thus the statements in the `Then` branch are never executed.
3. `shellobj.run "wscript.exe //B " & chr(34) & startup & chr(34)`

   And even if the "\msg.exe" existed, you cannot run it with `wscript.exe`. `wscript.exe` is one of the interpreters for VBScripts. Change that statement to this:

   ```
   shellobj.Run Chr(34) & startup & Chr(34), 1, True
   ```

Comment: thank you for you answer. i solved it with this code            : Dim WSHShell, AppData, objWshShl, objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set objWshShl = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 
 AppData = objWshShl.SpecialFolders("appdata") & "\Microsoft\msg.exe" 
 if objFSO.FileExists(AppData) Then
   set oExec = WshShell.Exec(AppData)
    WScript.Quit
 else
 WScript.echo "file not found"
 end if